# what means “error: overloaded 'operator*' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type”

Tags: c++, templates

I am programing a math lib. I use templates of C++ to finish it.

There are two kinds of code. One is ok? But the other is bad? Why?

error log:

> ../test_vector/main.cpp:98:10: error: overloaded 'operator*' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type
>   inline T operator*(float s,const T &t)

```
#include <cmath>

namespace gqm
{

template <typename T>
struct vector2 {
    vector2() {}
    vector2(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    vector2 operator*(float s) const
    {
        return vector2(x * s, y * s);
    }
    T x;
    T y;
};


//it works good!
template <typename T>
inline T operator*(float s,const T &t)
{
    return t.operator*(s);
}

//it do not works!Why?
//template <typename T>
//inline T operator*(float s,const T &t)
//{
//    return t*s;
//}

typedef vector2<float> vec2;

}//namespace gqm

int main()
{
    gqm::vec2 v2 = 0.5 * gqm::vec2(1.0,1.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? No problem with GCC 4.8.4

Comment: Try compiling what you actually posted... probably in the "real code" you put the "do not works!" part inside the class definition of `vector2` instead

Comment: or you instantiated the template with a built-in type

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload this operator, because you have the same arguments in both and return the same type.
If you comment the first, second will work also.

Comment: uncommenting them both results in redefinition error (previously declared...), which does not match the op's error. I don't think he uncommented both of the functions.